# How to interpret "Connection: keep-alive, close"?

Tags: http, standards

From what I understand, an HTTP connection could either be `keep-alive` or `close`.

I sent an HTTP request to a server:

```
GET /page1/ HTTP/1.1
Host: server.com
Connection: keep-alive
```

And it responded with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive, close
```

Essentially, I believe the server is bugged because a response like `keep-alive, close` is ambiguous.

However, as the **receiver**, how should we **handle** such a message? Should we **interpret** this header value as `keep-alive` or `close`?

Comment: Have you read the RFC of HTTP protocol? http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616

Comment: It might have to do with trying to support [certain] HTTP 1.0 clients, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection However, since `close` (which is defined in 1.1 is specified) then it's interpreted as "not a persistent connection" by a compliant HTTP 1.1 server/client?

Comment: @Jack, Doesn't seem to contain the answer.......

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**TL; DR: Chrome interprets this response header as `keep-alive` and maintain a peristent connection while Firefox closes each connection.**

I stumbled over this question as I tried to optimize the page loading time for my website.

In the referenced RFC I didn't find anything about how multiple entries in the `Connection` header may be properly handled. It seemed to me like the implementation may choose from two possibilites:

1. If there are multiple entries, you may choose that fits best to your needs
2. If there is a `close` inside, you may close the connection after transmission

So, I needed to find out. Let's make some deeper investigation:

I noticed that Chrome was always sending a HTTP/1.1 request with `Connection: keep-alive` and my Apache default configuration was always responding with a `Connection: close` header. So I began investigating and took a look at the TCP segments with Wireshark.

Chrome has to fetch 14 elements to display the website, mostly of them static things like images or css files. And it took in complete 14 TCP connections and that took a lot of time (approximately 1,2 seconds). After each request for an image (e.g.) there came a TCP segment with the `FIN` flag set to 1.

So what about Chrome vs. Firefox? Chrome seems to have a maximum number of concurrent connections to one server of 6. Firefox has a more granular configuration and distinguishs persistent (maxium of 6, seen in about:config) and non-persistent (the maximum numbers differed a lot in different sources). But wait... Both, Chrome and Firefox are sending HTTP/1.1 request headers with `Connection: keep-alive`, so both should be limited to 6 (as this is a request for opening up a persistent connection).

I decided to try a simple trick and added the following lines to my `.htaccess` in the web root folder:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
```

The server now responds with:

```
Connection: keep-alive, close
```

Now I took a look at the TCP segments again: There were only 9 connections from Chrome to my server now and only 3 with the `FIN` flag set to 1. So this trick seemed to work. But why were there those 3 connections, that closed the connection after data transmission? These were the PHP requests, as the HTTP header `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.11` confirmed.

And what about Firefox? There were still those 14 requests!

How to fix that and get the fcgi processes to work with keep-alive too?

I added the following lines to my virtualhost section of the httpd.conf configuration:

```
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 5
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
```

and removed the ones added in the `.htaccess`. Now the server isn't sending any confusing - `Connection: keep-alive, close`, but only `Connection: keep-alive` and everything works fine!

**Conclusion:**

A header with the connection field set to

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive, close
```

will be interpreted by Chrome as `keep-alive` while Firefox seems to close each connection. It seems to depend on the actual implementation.

So if you're willing to implement a client for handling response headers that contain `Connection: keep-alive, close`, I would propose to try using keep-alive if you need more than one request. The worst thing that may happen: The server will close the connection and you need to connect again (that's exactly the other option you would have had!)

Comment: What should be the *proper* behavior then?

Comment: As the RFC doesn't mention how to handle this situation, I would assume (if you're acting like a client): take the best possible for your needs! If there is nothing that needs to be transfered, close the connection, if there are still requests left in the queue, keep the connection alive. That's IMHO how Chrome handles it.

Comment: Doesn't it gets on the nerves when RFC is silent in so many aspects yet is supposed to be the authoritative guide?

Comment: Very interesting, did a google speedtest and it complains about this keep-alive, close thing and shows that keep-alive is NOT enabled. So I changed this into 'keep-alive' (without close) and speedtest 'warning' is gone.

Answer (score 5):

You are using `HTTP/1.1` but you are specifying `Connection: keep-alive`.

Under `HTTP/1.1` the `Connection: keep-alive` header has been deprecated, so you should not send it. All connections are keep-alive by default.

`Connection: keep-alive` was a little hack used back in the days of the so-called `HTTP/1.0+`.  (The `+` stands for "hacks necessary to get it to work.")

In *HTTP: The Definitive Guide* (by Brian Totty, Marjorie Sayer, Sailu Reddy, Anshu Aggarwal, David Gourley) by O'Reilly we read:

> Keep-alive is deprecated and no longer documented in the current HTTP/1.1 specification. However, keep-alive handshaking is still in relatively common use by browsers and servers, so HTTP implementors should be prepared to interoperate with it.

In HTTP lingo, "interoperate with someone" means "troll them hard by accepting any nonsense they send instead of issuing them an error." That's because web developers are the type of people who would rather be trolled *hard* than receive errors. (You know it is so, judging by how popular javascript is.) The result, of course, is preposterous situations like the one you have observed ("Connection: keep-alive, close" -- it takes a special kind of genius to return such a thing in a response) and many others which you will observe if you try with different servers, because each one of them will silently fail in a different way.

For more information about this, see [The Robustness Principle (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) (a.k.a. Postel's Law) (especially the "Criticism" section) and [Trevor Jim - Postel’s Law is not for you](https://trevorjim.com/postels-law-is-not-for-you/)

Answer (score 3):

It means that the server won't do persistent connections and will close the connection after this request.

Comment: Hmm then why did it say keep-alive in the first place?

Comment: Probably because you sent `keep-alive`. You should not send `keep-alive` as that's assumed for HTTP 1.1, `keep-alive` is used only for HTTP 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is at [RFC 7230 — 6.1. Connection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.1). It says:

> The Connection header field's value has the following grammar:
>
> ```
>  Connection        = 1#connection-option
>  connection-option = token
> ```

In Internet RFC parlance, the `1#connection-option` means at least one and at most any number of `connection-option`. This means there may be multiple options among which the receiver will pick anyone it prefers. That's not an ambiguity, that's a choice.

Comment: That's not the full syntax but a general one. While it may be valid to send more than one `connection-option`, that may be limited only to *certain* connection options. E.g. `Connection: keep-alive, close` wouuldn't make any sense as per section 6.2/6.3.